# Swift UIButton (inside framework) does not take action in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, swift, uibutton, frameworks

I have created a Swift framework to create a button and take an action, 
I want to import this framework in Objective C project, view showing the button but does not take any action

here is my Swift Framework Code:

```
 import Foundation

 @objc public class button:NSObject {

@objc public func addSingleButton(view: UIView){

    var button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: 
 .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(button)

   }


    @objc func buttonAction(){
        print("Hello World")

     }



  }
```

and here is my code in Objective C project

```
#import "ViewController.h"
 @import singleButton;

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

      button *p = [[button alloc] init];
      [p addSingleButtonWithView:self.view];



 }
```

Note: this does add button but does not print Hellow World, and note that I need this code to be done in Swift framework

Comment: Isn't this basically a repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036842/my-swift-framework-not-working-in-objectivec-but-works-fine-in-swift)? Instead of reposting, edit your original question as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy it was pretty long I needed to make something easier, that is in different scope but facing same problem